# The Area of Something Known Only in Volume

Tags: volume, area

In my worldbuilding, I have created a plain of lava that extended to a volume of 59 to 77 million cubic kilometers and 4500 meters at the thickest.

As I understand it, the basic formula of volume is as follows:

Area x Depth = Volume

So here is how I have imagined my imaginary lava flow at that formula:

??? x 4500 meters = 59 million cubic kilometers  (minimum)

??? x 4500 meters =  77 million cubic kilometers  (maximum)

What would the area be in this scenario?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?num=20&newwindow=1&safe=off&hl=en&site=webhp&q=59+million+cubic+kilometers+%2F+4500+meters+in+square+kilometers&oq=59+million+cubic+kilometers+%2F+4500+meters+in+square+kilometers https://www.google.com/search?num=20&newwindow=1&safe=off&hl=en&site=webhp&q=77+million+cubic+kilometers+%2F+4500+meters+in+square+kilometers&oq=77+million+cubic+kilometers+%2F+4500+meters+in+square+kilometers

Comment: @SteveKass  Thank you.

Comment: Did you got your answer?